# How to rotate camera around group of objects? (not using 3d engines)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, 3d, camera, point

So I create a point cloud, in 3d with code like (flash 10.1 CS5):

```
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.BitmapData;

var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(400, 400, true, 0xFFCCCCCC);

                var xn:Number;
                var yn:Number;
                var zn:Number;
                var norm:Number;
                var c1:Number;
                var c2:Number;
                var c3:Number;
                var c4:Number;
                var counter:int;
    var color:uint


                while (counter < 100000)
                {
                    xn = Math.random() * 600 - 200;
                    yn = Math.random() * 600 - 200;
                    zn = Math.random() * 600 - 200;
                    norm = Math.sqrt(xn * xn + yn * yn + zn * zn);
                    c1 = (1 - norm / 200) * 255;
                    c2 = (1 - norm / 250) * 255;
                    c3 = Math.abs(xn) / norm * 255;
                    c4 = Math.abs(yn) / norm * 255;
                    color =  (c1 << 24 | c2 << 16 | c3 << 8 | c4);
                    counter++;

      var pointGraphicData = new BitmapData(1,1,true,color)
var pointGraphic:Bitmap = new Bitmap(pointGraphicData);

pointGraphic.x = xn;
pointGraphic.y = yn;
pointGraphic.z = zn;
addChild(pointGraphic);
}
```

How to move and rotate camera that looks onto the screen in sphere like path

[image]

around created box?

Answer (score 0):

There's a javascript example of how to create a spiral on a sphere surface at this link:

http://lines-about-to-be-generated.blogspot.com/2009/06/image-spiral-sphere.html

Answer (score 0):

You want an [Archimedian Spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral).  You should be able to find tons of equations via google.

You'll want to:

1. Find center point of point cloud
2. Set camera facing center point
3. Calculate position *p* of camera at time *t* on Archimedian spiral
4. Set camera position to *p*
5. Render and display frame
6. Repeat from 3. until finished